# Visual Studio - Code Formatting (curly braces)

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style, indentation

I am in trouble with the `Visual Studio 2013` code formatting. In particoular I have the following *problem*: when I cut and paste some C++/C# code it is re-formatted as follow:

```
int main() {
  ...
}
```

While I would prefer the following indentation (please note the position of the opening curly brace):

```
int main()
{
  ...
}
```

Where can I find the proper indentation setting?

Comment: Egyptian braces, you can change that.  Spend some time in Tools > Options > Text Editor to pick your preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> New Lines` and choose what suits you. Then, do the same thing for `C#` settings.